# Best way to hide background image in Drupal with certain URL patterns

Tags: css, background, hide

What would be the most effectient way to hide a background image if the url has node in it it?

I have set a background image that runs through the site however I dont want the background image to show if the url has node in it. For example,

http://example.com/node

http://example.com/node/add.

The site uses drupal and my css is entry level to be polite!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know in pure CSS there isn't a way to do what you are trying. However, I am pretty sure that Drupal would find a way to prove me wrong. :-)

The best way to do this would be to create a new stylesheet or style for the pages that have `node` in the URL and override the default background. You can do that by using the following code:

`background-image: none;`

But remember that this should be called **after** the common stylesheet that is on all the pages otherwise you will see the background image on the `node` pages as well.